# CGI application misbehaved by not returning a complete set of HTTP headers

Tags: delphi, cgi, c++builder

Hi someone created one application "ReqServ"  using Code gear Delphi 2009 and C++ Builder 2009. This application returns chart images. This application is called through URL like `"http:/ /machine_name/MONITOR/ReqServ.exe"`. Previously this application was working good and displays the charts in Internet Explorer.

But someone uninstalled the Code gear RAD application and other installed application from that machine.

Now when I am trying to access that URL its displying me "CGI application misbehaved by not returning a complete set of HTTP headers".

I searched on the internet and I found below link: 
"http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/21574"
which tells that this error might be due to run time packages.

I opened the project(.bpr extenstion) in C++ Builder 2009 and found that "Build With Runtime packages" is checked.

Is there any way that without installing RAD 2009 or any other applcation I can make this "RegServ" run. I have backup of Code Gear folder from program Files. But I am confused where I can place these files now.

Or is there any other way to resolve this error? Thaks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to run the exe file from a command prompt on the server? If so you should see the exact error that is returned (and in fact will make an incomplete set of HTTP headers).

If it says which file(s) it is missing, search them in the Program Files backup, and copy them to the `%WINDIR%\SYSTEM32` folder. If it doesn't, it'll probably be the `*.bpl` files of which the EDN article mentions a few.

Comment: Calling from coomand prrompt I am not getting any error. It just runs and terminates in fraction of seconds.

Comment: any other possibility that causing the CGI Error?